# Conditional Expectation where the conditioning variable is unknown

Tags: probability

I've been asked to define the "expectation of X given Y" (i.e when we don't know what Y is). (NOT "Expectation of X given Y=y" - this one I can do :) ). Frankly I have no idea - as far as I can tell, there is no standard formula for this?

It's given that X's are iid, and Y's are positive integer (discrete). X's do have a finite expectation. It's not stated that X,Y are independent (cos it would be much easier if they were).  Ideas?

Comment: How many random variables are involved here?  You refer to "$X$'s", but also refer to $X$ as a single random variable...

Comment: I may have just been having a brain-malfunction... is it the same as "the sum of (x * P(X=x given Y))" ?

Comment: The question does not specify how many X's there are. It just says: Let Xsub0, Xsub1, Xsub2...be indep and iid rv's. So I guess there's infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

This requires two random variables $X$ and $Y$, defined on the same probability space, and such that $X$ is integrable. Then there exists a unique measurable function $u$ such that the random variable $u(Y)$ is integrable and such that, for every Borel subset $B$,
$$
E[X\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}]=E[u(Y)\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}].
$$
This random variable $u(Y)$ is called the conditional expectation of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ and denoted $E[X\mid Y]$.

An alternative definition is to ask for an integrable random variable $Z$, measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra $\sigma(Y)$ generated by $Y$, and such that, for every Borel subset $B$, $E[X\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}]=E[Z\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}]$.

It is a classical exercise to show that this extends the elementary notion of conditioning, in the following sense: when the distribution of $Y$ is discrete, the function $u$ may be defined by $u(y)=E[X\mid Y=y]$ for every $y$ such that $P[Y=y]\ne0$, and by $u(y)=0$ elsewhere. Thus, when $Y$ is discrete, one sometimes defines $E[X\mid Y]$ as the random variable $u(Y)$ where $u:y\mapsto E[X\mid Y=y]$.